# How to store many attributes at once?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, initialization

I'm working with Swift, Xcode 6 and SpriteKit,

I want make a game where some sprites fall down from the top of the screen, but each sprite have a defined speed, position and activation time. I have this working code, but I really don't think that it's the most optimised way to do it:

```
class obstacles: SKSpriteNode
{
    var isOnScreen = false
    var type: Int = 0
    var initTime: Int = 0
}

var obstacle = [obstacles]() // obstacle is an array of SKSpriteNode

// type : initTime : speed : position : xScale : yScale
var level1: [String] = ["0:120:3:0:1:1", "0:130:4:80:2:2","1:140:8:120:6:1","0:150:6:240:2:2"]

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
{        
    initObstacles()
}

func initObstacles()
{
    for var x = 0; x < level1.count; x++ // for each obstacle
    {
        var index = 0

        var type = String("")
        var initTime = String("")
        var speed = String("")
        var position = String("")
        var xScale = String("")
        var yScale = String("")

        var lastIndex = obstacle.count

        for Character in level1[x] // we read each character one by one
        {
            if Character == ":" { index++ } // if it's a ":" we change the variable
            else
            {
                switch index
                {
                case 0:
                    type += String(Character)
                case 1:
                    initTime += String(Character)
                case 2:
                    speed += String(Character)
                case 3:
                    position += String(Character)
                case 4:
                    xScale += String(Character)
                case 5:
                    yScale += String(Character)
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        obstacle.append(obstacles(imageNamed: "Rectangle")) // we add an element to the array

        obstacle[lastIndex].type = type.toInt()! // we init all the values
        obstacle[lastIndex].initTime = initTime.toInt()!
        obstacle[lastIndex].speed = CGFloat(speed.toInt()!)
        obstacle[lastIndex].size.width = DEFAULT_OBSTACLE_SIZE * CGFloat(xScale.toInt()!)
        obstacle[lastIndex].size.height = DEFAULT_OBSTACLE_SIZE * CGFloat(yScale.toInt()!)
        obstacle[lastIndex].position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(position.toInt()!) - obstacle[lastIndex].size.width/2, CGRectGetMaxY(frame) + obstacle[lastIndex].size.height/2)
    }
}
```

Do you know how could I manage to do the same thing, but more "clean" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to create a `class` or `struct` that holds all necessary data for an obstacle and additionally change your type from a standard number to an `enum`, e.g.:

```
enum ObstacleType {
    case Block, Tree, WhatEverObstaclesYouHave...
}
struct Obstacle {
    var type: ObstacleType
    var initializationTime: NSTimeInterval
    var speed: Double
    // and similarly for position, your scales and what you may need in future
}
```

and create them using, e.g.

```
Obstacle(type: .Block, initializationTime: 0, speed: 12.0, ...)
```

Advantage (obviously) is that you have no problems anymore parsing your string (there is no string anymore) and can provide all necessary information using the appropriate type directly. And you can easily use an enum for your type, which should be an enum, because your Obstacle is not a `1`, but a Block, Tree or whatever.

Your `level1` variable could then be defined like this:

```
var level1 : [Obstacle] = [
    Obstacle(type: .Block, initializationTime: 120, speed: 3.0, ...),
    Obstacle(type: .Block, initializationTime: 130, speed: 4.0, ...),
    Obstacle(type: .Tree,  initializationTime: 140, speed: 8.0, ...),
    Obstacle(type: .Block, initializationTime: 150, speed: 6.0, ...)
]
```

---

To get rid of the labels in the initializer, just define your own initializer. Just add this to your struct:

```
init(_ type: ObstacleType, _ time: NSTimeInterval, _ speed: Double, ...) {
    self.type = type
    self.initializationTime = time
    self.speed = speed
    // other variables...
}
```

Then you can create every Obstacle like this:

```
Obstacle(.Block, 120, 3.0, ...)
```

But now you can not easily tell anymore which number has what meaning from reading the instantiation. I do not recommend this just to type less as autocomplete will present you with most of it.

Comment: Okay thanks, but I want defined levels, every level will be the same, so I have to initialise every obstacle of the level with every correspondant value at the beginning, and I don't know how to do it, because I can easily have one hundred obstacles in one level ...

Comment: @Drakalex So, you simply have too many obstacles and do not want to set all the values manually?

Comment: No I have to set all the values manually, but that's not the problem, I don't know what is the best way to set all the values ? I want to have something like `var level1: [String] = ["0:120:3:0:1:1", "0:130:4:80:2:2","1:140:8:120:6:1","0:150:6:240:2:2"]` this represents the first 4 obstacles with their parameters

Comment: @Drakalex I added an example for your `level1`. I translated your type 0 to Block and type 1 to Tree. Adjust that as needed.

Comment: okay thanks it's exactly what I wanted, but is there any way to avoid typing type: , initializationTime, speed etc... ? like `Obstacle(.Block,150,6.0, ...)`

Comment: One more thing : all of my obstacles are SKSPriteNode, so they have my specific values (type, initializationTime etc...) but they also have their SKSPriteNode values which are speed, color, zRotation etc... So I need to replace the `struct Obstacles` by `class Obstacles: SKSPriteNode`, but when I do so the code doesn't work anymore !

Comment: @Drakalex Of course, you have to adapt the code to the SKSpriteNode. So you have to rename the speed variable (SKSpriteNode already has one for some other purpose) and add a call to the initializer of the super class in your initializer, e.g. `super.init(texture: SKTexture!, color:UIColor!, size:CGSize)` and maybe other things. As these are really basic questions, I recommend you to have a look at the [Swift documentation by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html) which contains a lot of information.

Comment: I already tried to read the documentation, but I don't find what i'm looking for, I tried again but I failed once more...
I don't know how I could have an array of SKSPriteNode which represents my level, and each element of the array, each SKSPriteNode is already initialised with constant values that I have chosen, and thoses values can be the variables of my subclass Obstacles like initTime and type for example, and also the attributes of the superclass SKSpriteNode like speed, zRotation etc...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67130/discussion-between-nero-and-drakalex).